# pure-pw error: Unable to open the passwd file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, ftp

I get this error when i want to run the following command: `pure-pw list`

> Unable to open the passwd file: No such file or directory

I remove manually the folder `/etc/pure-ftpd/` and I think this is the root of the problem. So i tried to regenerate it by reinstalling **pure-ftpd**, but i still don't have this folder.

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Which error are you referring too..

Comment: @Mongrel it's written in the title

Comment: @Mongrel just edited

Answer (score 3):

For those with same trouble in Red Hat or Centos default *yum installation*.

1. Open `/etc/pure-ftpd/pure-ftpd.conf`, 
   uncomment line above

   ```
   #PureDB                        /etc/pure-ftpd/pureftpd.pdb
   ```
2. Create the *passwd* file

   ```
   touch /etc/pure-ftpd/pureftpd.passwd
   ```
3. Restart Pure-Ftpd service or create the database file

   ```
   systemctl stop pure-ftpd; systemctl start pure-ftpd
   ```

   or

   ```
   pure-pw mkdb -F /etc/pure-ftpd/pureftpd.pdb
   ```

Now you can create your ftpusers.

Answer (score 0):

If you definitely have created a user with:

```
pure-pw useradd
```

Then try linking your files and restarting pure-ftpd:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/pure-ftpd/pureftpd.passwd /etc/pureftpd.passwd
sudo ln -s /etc/pure-ftpd/pureftpd.pdb /etc/pureftpd.pdb
sudo ln -s /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/PureDB /etc/pure-ftpd/auth/PureDB
systemctl restart pure-ftpd
```

Guide on a complete setup for ubuntu.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PureFTP

Answer (score -2):

Use this, I have the same problem and I have solved it.

```
apt-get --purge remove pure-ftpd-common

apt-get install pure-ftpd-common
```